# How do I place a non-tab item in a jQuery UI Tab Bar using valid XHTML?

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui, tabs

I am creating a standard jQuery UI tab bar, nothing special except for the following: I would like to include a hyperlink on the right-hand side of the tab bar to serve as a log-out button. I know that I can accomplish this using *invalid* XHTML by writing the tab container like this:

```
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="tab1.jsp">Tab 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="tab2.jsp">Tab 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="tab3.jsp">Tab 3</a></li>

            <span class="logout">
                <a href="logout.jsp">Log out</a>
            </span>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

and using the CSS:

```
.logout
{
   float: right;
}
```

It works beautifully, but it's also not valid (because of the `span` child of the `ul`).

Is there a correct way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you just put the span as a child of the div instead of the ul? Obviously you'd have to change the css a tiny bit.

Comment: I could probably finagle that - my first shot at it left the logout link behind (mostly obscured by) the tab bar. Any idea how I can change that?

Comment: Got it! added to my CSS `padding: .6em; position: relative; z-index: 1;` and it's all good.